# 'Cosa dite se mangiamo insieme questa sera?' o 'Vi andrebbe di cenare insieme stasera?'

Tags: grammar, phrases

Qual è la forma più corretta fra le due frasi: **Cosa dite se mangiamo insieme questa sera?** o **Vi andrebbe di cenare insieme stasera?**?

Comment: Spesso non c'è una forma più corretta di un'altra: ci sono innumerevoli modi per formulare più o meno lo stesso concetto, o proposta come in questo caso. (Invece “qual è” è ben più corretto di *“qual'è”.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Cosa ne dite; vi va; vi andrebbe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cosa%20ne%20dite%2Cvi%20va%20%2Cvi%20andrebbe&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccosa%20ne%20dite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvi%20va%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvi%20andrebbe%3B%2Cc0)*** (opportunamente declinate per numero e genere)    sono tutte expressioni informali usate per chiedere il parere a qualcuno riguardo ad un suggerimento o un'idea.